# ImageSize in Export

Tags: export

According to the documentation, `Export["foo.eps", out, ImageSize->500]` should produce a graphic that is 500 printer points wide. When I execute that command with varying numbers in place of 500, I get eps files that are identical; they all have bounding boxes of `0, 0, 260, 291`. Am I missing something? (I could have sworn that this used to work in an earlier version, but I may be mistaken).

Comment: I've never used ImageSize as an argument for Export, but I have often used ImageResolution -> 200, for example, to make sure that the resolution is 200 points per inch. Usually ImageSize is an argument to Graphics[] or Graphics3D[]; Export[name, Graphics[..., ImageSize -> 5 * 72], ImageResolution -> 100] would export an image that is 5 inches wide with 100 points per inch.

Comment: @ user21382  Why you do not formulate this as a regular answer? I find your comment contains an information that might be of a general interest.